# Place items on a path in Items control

Tags: wpf, xaml

Hi i am working on a WPF application and i require to place the items on a U shape path on a panel

So I am using the following code but it places the items in a queue as i have used the stack panel. so is there any way to place items on a predefined path as i keep on adding elements to data source they should be placed on a predefined path.

```
<ItemsControl Name="icTodoList" Grid.Row="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentsItemsSource}"  Width="100" Height="460" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{Binding}" Content="{Binding Path=ItemName}" Height="35" Width="35" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I don't know if there is something like this, but it could be fairly easy to implement using [adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx)

Comment: You could create a custom panel as shown in [How to: Create a Custom Panel Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753321(v=vs.110).aspx), and use that in your ItemsPanelTemplate.